# UITabBarController using multiple storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I am working on refactoring my huge storyboard to multiple storyboards. During the process I am struggling to get the tab bar image to show up.

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController{

    @IBOutlet weak var myTabBar: UITabBar?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setTabBarItems()
    }

    func setTabBarItems(){
        guard let tabBar1 = self.tabBar.items?[0] else { return }
        let myTabBarItem1 = tabBar1 as UITabBarItem
        myTabBarItem1.image = UIImage(named: "1-tab-bar-unselected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        myTabBarItem1.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "1-tab-bar-selected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        myTabBarItem1.title = ""
        guard let tabBar2 = self.tabBar.items?[1] else { return }
        let myTabBarItem2 = tabBar2 as UITabBarItem
        myTabBarItem2.image = UIImage(named: "2-tab-bar-unselected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        myTabBarItem2.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "2-tab-bar-selected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        myTabBarItem2.title = ""
        guard let tabBar3 = self.tabBar.items?[2] else { return }
        let myTabBarItem3 = tabBar3 as UITabBarItem
        myTabBarItem3.image = UIImage(named: "3")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        myTabBarItem3.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "3-tab-bar-selected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        myTabBarItem3.title = ""
        guard let tabBar4 = self.tabBar.items?[3] else { return }
        let myTabBarItem4 = tabBar4 as UITabBarItem
        myTabBarItem4.image = UIImage(named: "4-tab-bar-unselected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        myTabBarItem4.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "4-tab-bar-selected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        myTabBarItem4.title = ""
        guard let tabBar5 = self.tabBar.items?[4] else { return }
        let myTabBarItem5 = tabBar5 as UITabBarItem
        myTabBarItem5.image = UIImage(named: "5-tab-bar-unselected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        myTabBarItem5.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "5-tab-bar-selected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        myTabBarItem5.title = ""
    }
}
```

This is what I had previously and was working. Currently it doesn't show any items image only "Items". I have added a tab bar item to the navigation view controller.

**What I have tried** 
・Instantiated VC from UITabBarController
・set the nav item in the settings navigation view controller, this works but the tab bar is empty when app launched.

Any help is appreciated

[image]

Comment: Did you set the image of Tab bar item on the navigation controller?

Comment: And for the storyboard reference of Settings.storyboard, have you used viewcontroller's id as reference id or navigation controller's id?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes I have set the image of tab bar item on the nav controller. When I tap on the tab then the icon appears. It doesn't appear when app launches.  I have used  navigation controller's id for reference

Comment: well you should create tabbar class and then set the tabbar icon to that class and your icon will appear.

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment isn't it what I am doing?  I do have a tabbar class

Comment: can you add the images of how it is coming right now when you run the app?

Comment: No image is shown. just the word "Item"

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController{
override func viewDidLoad() {
       self.viewControllers![3].title = "Your Title" //This for title
       self.tabBar.items?[0].image = UIImage(named: "YourImageName")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal) // This for image

}
```

When your image is not coming means your image size not correct because i'm also facing same problem.
The image may be of a size that is too large to show up. Tab Bar item images should be around 28pt-32pt (pixels) in size.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Image size is ok because it was working before I created multiple storyboards. The code is exactly the same thing that I have written in my question.